# Foursquare API (explore venues) not returning url and menu url

Tags: foursquare

When I make an api call (see bottom) to retrieve the request, foursquare is not including all venue data. The json output, tells me that the venue has a menu (via hasMenu = true), but doesn't return a menu object. Anybody else experiencing this problem?

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret= CLIENT_SECRET&v=20150804&ll=latitude,longitude&section=food &venuePhotos=1&m=foursquare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`m=foursquare` is not necessary. Please try following URL:

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret= CLIENT_SECRET&v=20150804&ll=latitude,longitude&section=food &venuePhotos=1

Comment: Thanks. Urls are loading now :D